# Counting occurences of duplicates in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame which contains many duplicates of rows and I would like to count the number of times each duplicate appears in the table. To find the duplicates, I use drop_duplicates:

```
duplicates = data.drop_duplicates()
```

What is the simplest way of counting the number of times each row of 'duplicates' appears in 'data'?

Comment: `data.duplicated().sum()`?

Comment: I think it will count the number of duplicated rows. But rows which are duplicated are not all the same. I would like to know how many times each duplicated row appears.

Comment: In other words, I would like to apply a kind of unique() function to the list of rows (this is what I do with drop_duplicates) and then count the number of occurences in the original DataFrame for each element of the return value of the unique() function.

Comment: See my updated answer if it's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 data.groupby([*data]).size()
```

Test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1]*5 + [2]*3 + [3,4],
    'col2': [2]*5 + [3]*3 + [4,4]
})
```

Output:

```
col1  col2
1     2       5
2     3       3
3     4       1
4     4       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you explain? I get a syntax error with '*data'.

Comment: `[*data]` is equivalent to `list(data.columns)`. You group by all the columns in `data`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine with list(data.columns)

Comment: I try to undersand why it does not work with *data and then I mark you answer as the solution.

Comment: I tried your example and I also got a syntax error.

Comment: It's ok! My pandas version was outdated. Thanks again!